# Pandas merge two df's where df1.column is = or between df2.column1 and df2.column2

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, between

I can't seem to find this example anywhere. Having trouble determining if I need to use indexes, boolean mask, or if a direct merge is possible. I've tried variations of `.isin` and `.between` each to no success.

**Scenario:**

- Two dataFrames with no common index:

  ```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'printId': ['x','y', 'z', 'a'],'locCode': [0.9, 1.5, 4.0, 7.8]})
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({'assetId': ['1','1a', '2', '2a', '3', '4'], 'locStart': [0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 4, 8], 'locEnd': [0.9, 0.9, 3, 3, 5, 13]})
  ```

**df1:**

[image]

**df2:**

[image]

**Need this:**

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'printId': ['x','x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'NaN'], 'locCode': ['0.9', '0.9', '1.5', '1.5', '4.0', '7.8', 'NaN'], 'assetID': ['1', '1a', '2', '2a', '3', 'NaN', '4'], 'locStart': ['0.9', '0.9', '1.0', '1.0', '4.0', 'NaN', '8.0'], 'locEnd':['0.9', '0.9', '3.0', '3.0', '4.0', 'NaN', '13.0']})
```

**df3**

[image]

How do professionals attack this problem?

**EDITED:** Original answer did not work after closer examination.

- Where `df2` has duplicated `locStart/End` records, but unique `assetID` (row 0, 1 and row 2 and 3), `df1` will not merge.

Comment: I dont understand leftmiss and rightmiss exactly. Is it true left miss means df1 record whose locCode is not between any codestart and codeend in df2?

Showing your expected result as dataframe will help me to answer the question.

Comment: @GilseungAhn, For expected result, please refer to the last image shown in post. "HitList" = a list where df1's = or fall between columns in df2. Ex: Row2 and 3 above. "LeftMiss" = a list of df1's that do not have a corresponding df2. Ex: Row 1 and 4 above. "RightMiss" = a list of df2's that do not have a corresponding df1. Ex: Row 0 and 5 above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works also if there are duplicates of locStart, locEnd in df2 (with unique assetId's)

It also handles the case if in df1 there duplicate in printId or locCode

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'printId': ['x','y', 'z', 'a'],'locCode': [0.9, 1.5, 4.0, 7.8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'assetId': ['1','1a', '2', '2a', '3', '4'], 'locStart': [0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 4, 8], 'locEnd': [0.9, 0.9, 3, 3, 5, 13]})


merge_id = []

for i,code in df1.locCode.iteritems():
    filled = True
    partial = []
    for j,row in df2.iterrows():
        if code>=row.locStart and code<=row.locEnd:
            filled = False
            partial.append(j)
    if filled:
        partial.append(-1)
    merge_id.append(partial)

df1['merge_id'] = merge_id

df = df1.explode('merge_id').merge(df2, right_index=True, left_on='merge_id', how='outer')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).drop('merge_id', axis=1)


print(df)
  printId  locCode assetId  locStart  locEnd
0       x      0.9       1       0.9     0.9
1       x      0.9      1a       0.9     0.9
2       z      4.0       3       4.0     5.0
3       y      1.5       2       1.0     3.0
4       y      1.5      2a       1.0     3.0
5       a      7.8     NaN       NaN     NaN
6     NaN      NaN       4       8.0    13.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'printId': ['01','1A', '2B', '3C'],'locCode': [0.9, 1.5, 4.0, 7.8], 'a1': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'assetId': ['oo', 'aa', 'zz', 'xx'], 'locCodeStart': [0, 1, 4, 8], 'locCodeEnd': [0.4, 3, 5, 13]})

df1['assetId'] = np.nan
for ind, row in df1.iterrows():
    loc_code = row['locCode']
    temp = (df2['locCodeStart'] <= loc_code) & (loc_code < df2['locCodeEnd'])
    df2_index = temp[temp == True].index
    if len(df2_index) == 1:
        df1['assetId'].loc[ind] = df2['assetId'].loc[df2_index[0]]

pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer')
```

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. I made one change to: `temp = (loc_code >= df2['locCodeStart']) & (loc_code <= df2['locCodeEnd'])` per the requirements. Alas, I also found a breaking change: When there are overlapping locCodes. Example: Substitute the following df's: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'printId': ['01','1A', '2B', '3C'],'locCode': [0.4, 1.5, 4.0, 8], 'a1': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'assetId': ['22','oo', 'aa', 'zz', 'xx'], 'locCodeStart': [2, 0, 1, 4, 8], 'locCodeEnd': [4, 0.4, 3, 5, 13]})`. One record to df2 with a locEndCode matching a locStartCode.

Comment: @Gilseung Ahn: How would I adjust the code to accommodate for `locCodeStart` and `locCodeEnd` that are the same value? The above does not work in this case.

Comment: Wow! @GilseungAhn : I changed `temp = (df2['locCodeStart'] <= loc_code) & (loc_code < df2['locCodeEnd'])` to `temp = ( loc_code >= df2['locCodeStart'] ) & (loc_code <= df2['locCodeEnd']) and now the code does just what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the start/end locCodes are the same for multiple records in df2 as shown in the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it handle two cases differently. first case is simple `merge` where df1.locCode exist in df2.locStart, the second case by creating bins with all the values locStart and locEnd in both df1 and df2, then `merge` them after removing the cases already handled in the first merge:

```
## handle the case where locCode of df1 is equal to locStart of df2

# get the rows in this case
mask_merge = df1['locCode'].isin(df2['locStart'].unique())

# handle them with a direct
m1 = df1[mask_merge].merge(df2, right_on='locStart', left_on='locCode', how='inner')

## handle the other cases

# get unique values from df2 both columns loc
l_unique = pd.concat([df2['locStart'], df2['locEnd']]).sort_values().unique()

# add cat columns with pd.cut in both dataframe with all unique values
df2['cat'] = pd.cut(df2['locEnd'], bins=[-np.inf]+l_unique.tolist() + [+np.inf],
                    labels=range(len(l_unique)+1))
df1['cat'] = pd.cut(df1['locCode'], bins=[-np.inf]+l_unique.tolist() + [+np.inf],
                    labels=range(len(l_unique)+1))

# mask to get which asser does not have same start and end
mask_startEnd = df2['locStart'].ne(df2['locEnd'])
# mask assert already merged above
mask_df2merged = ~df2['locStart'].isin(df1['locCode'])

# merge the rows needed
m2 = df1[~mask_merge].merge(df2[mask_startEnd&mask_df2merged], on='cat', how='outer')

#concat both and drop column cat
res = pd.concat([m1, m2], axis=0, ignore_index=True).drop('cat', axis=1)

print (res)
  printId  locCode assetId  locStart  locEnd
0       x      0.9       1       0.9     0.9
1       x      0.9      1a       0.9     0.9
2       z      4.0       3       4.0     5.0
3       y      1.5       2       1.0     3.0
4       y      1.5      2a       1.0     3.0
5       a      7.8     NaN       NaN     NaN
6     NaN      NaN       4       8.0    13.0
```

Comment: Haven't got around to testing this one as the first solution I tested (Marco) is working.